# CommandLineRunner & graceful shutdown

Tags: spring-boot

How to make Spring `CommandLineRunner` shutdown gracefully?

```java
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(DemoApplication.class);

    @Value("${server.shutdown}")
    private String serverShutdown;

    @Value("${spring.lifecycle.timeout-per-shutdown-phase}")
    private String timeout;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws InterruptedException {

        log.info("server.shutdown: " + this.serverShutdown);
        log.info("spring.lifecycle.timeout-per-shutdown-phase: " + this.timeout);

        log.info("Starting...");

        int i = 1000;

        while (--i > 0) {
            log.info("Running...");
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
        }

        log.info("Done.");
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void tearDown() {
        log.info("Shutting Down!");
    }
}
```

Running the code above with `./mvnw spring-boot:run` and hitting Ctrl+C will print the following output:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::               (v2.7.11)

2023-04-30 13:12:25.575  INFO 17558 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication using Java 11.0.17 on WS0 with PID 17558 (/home/asd/temp/java/GracefulShutdown/demo/target/classes started by asd in /home/asd/temp/java/GracefulShutdown/demo)
2023-04-30 13:12:25.577  INFO 17558 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-04-30 13:12:25.934  INFO 17558 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 0.647 seconds (JVM running for 0.903)
2023-04-30 13:12:25.940  INFO 17558 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : server.shutdown: graceful
2023-04-30 13:12:25.941  INFO 17558 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : spring.lifecycle.timeout-per-shutdown-phase: 1m
2023-04-30 13:12:25.941  INFO 17558 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting...
2023-04-30 13:12:25.941  INFO 17558 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Running...
2023-04-30 13:12:28.942  INFO 17558 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Running...
^C2023-04-30 13:12:30.597  INFO 17558 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Shutting Down!
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  7.620 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-04-30T13:12:30+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As can be seen from the logs the shutdown happens immediately after pressing Ctrl+C (sending a SIGTERM with `kill -15 <process id>` will do the same).

I am expecting it to wait for sixty seconds as configured in the `application.properties` config file:

```
server.shutdown=graceful
spring.lifecycle.timeout-per-shutdown-phase=1m
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the `server.shutdown` [setting](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-web-server-shutdown) is for a web server, not command line.

I guess I have to build my own theme park. First, a helper class for thread-safe communication:

```java
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

public class ShutdownAwaiter {

    private final BlockingQueue<Boolean> stopRequested = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Boolean>();
    private final BlockingQueue<Boolean> canStop = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Boolean>();

    public Boolean isStopRequested() {
        return !this.stopRequested.isEmpty();
    }

    public void awaitStop() {
        try {
            stopRequested.add(true);
            canStop.take();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        canStop.add(true);
    }
}
```

Then using it in the main method:

```java
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(DemoApplication.class);

    private final ShutdownAwaiter shutdownAwaiter = new ShutdownAwaiter();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws InterruptedException {

        log.info("Starting...");

        while (!shutdownAwaiter.isStopRequested()) {
            log.info("Running...");
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
        }

        log.info("Done.");

        shutdownAwaiter.stop();
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void tearDown() {
        log.info("Shutting Down!");
        shutdownAwaiter.awaitStop();
    }
}
```

The logs now have the "Done." line confirming graceful shutdown:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::               (v2.7.11)

2023-04-30 13:20:05.020  INFO 21973 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication using Java 11.0.17 on WS0 with PID 21973 (/home/asd/temp/java/GracefulShutdown/demo/target/classes started by asd in /home/asd/temp/java/GracefulShutdown/demo)
2023-04-30 13:20:05.022  INFO 21973 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-04-30 13:20:05.384  INFO 21973 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 0.642 seconds (JVM running for 0.902)
2023-04-30 13:20:05.386  INFO 21973 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting...
2023-04-30 13:20:05.386  INFO 21973 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Running...
2023-04-30 13:20:08.387  INFO 21973 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Running...
^C2023-04-30 13:20:08.956  INFO 21973 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Shutting Down!
2023-04-30 13:20:11.388  INFO 21973 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Done.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  9.030 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-04-30T13:20:11+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

The property `timeout-per-shutdown-phase` is the *maximum* amount of time to wait until a phase is ready to be shutdown. From the docs:

> Timeout for the shutdown of any phase (group of SmartLifecycle beans with the same 'phase' value).

In the example you shared the Spring context is ready to be shut down gracefully immediately after your send sigterm as there is nothing holding it back.

Comment: Can I somehow block the context until the `CommandLineRunner` implementation is finished?

Comment: Please raise a different question as I'm not sure it is what was asked inititially.

Comment: The question was literally "How to make Spring CommandLineRunner shutdown gracefully?" and IMO it is pretty clear - I was seeking a way to prevent Spring from killing my worker loop prematurely. There is also further clarification towards the end: "I am expecting it to wait for sixty seconds..." (before getting killed). With my answer I have achieved that. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction!